# three.js warped boxhelper and inaccurate object position

Tags: javascript, three.js

This THREE.BoxHelper is wildly inaccurate, and the position of the cube is not accurate when drawing a line to it!?

See the proof of concept JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/can35bj0/15/

```
cubeBox = new THREE.BoxHelper(cube, 0xffff00)
scene.add(cubeBox);
cube.position.copy(positionVector);
cubeTrace.geometry.vertices[cubeTrace.geometry.vertices.length - 1].copy(cube.position);
```

Why is this, and is there a way to fix this? So far I've come up empty...

p.s. scales and position need to be small vs. large

Answer (score 0):

I've more or less concluded that this is due to a 'long vector' problem of THREE.js.

When an object (such as the square cube in the JSFiddle) is on a long arm from Origin compared to it's size, in this case the positionVector is roughly 100,000 units and the cube size is 0.001 units, positions become erratic and fluctuating as can be seen by the weird behavior of the Boxhelper. (Note that the cube is set to move slightly every second and the camera moves with it)